# HTML5 video tag youtube

Tags: html, video, youtube

I found a solution to put a youtube link into a HTML tag, but it does not work, the video is not displayed:

```
<video controls="controls" x-webkit-airplay="allow" class="video-stream" 
  src="http://youtu.be/8sUr5uBFInQ"></video>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [**this blog**](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html), you need a different syntax.

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" 
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" allowfullscreen frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```